# how to match the first pattern behind some pattern in regex

Tags: regex

I want to find the year SOMETHING happens (the closest year string pattern, maybe 2016y or 16y or 2016y1m3d, before the key word SOMETHING) and mark it, for example, change

> '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens'

to

> '2015y, balabala; **<mark>2016y3m4d<mark>**, SOMETHING happens'

simply match the year and key word 'SOMETHING' will not work, as

```
echo '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens' \
    | perl -ne 's/(\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)(.*)(SOMETHING)/<mark>\1<mark>\2\3/g; print;'
```

will output

> **<mark>2015y<mark>**, balabala; 2016y, SOMETHING happens

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the pattern matching nearest to the string `SOMETHING`.
Modifying a bit of your regex only

```
echo '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens' 
| perl -ne 's/(.*)\b(\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)\b(.*?)(SOMETHING)/\1<mark>\2<mark>\3\4/g; print;'
```

**or**

```
echo '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens'     
| perl -ne 's/(.*)\b(\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)\b(.*?SOMETHING)/\1<mark>\2<mark>\3/g; print;'
```

Comment: good idea. what if SOMETHING occurs multiple times, like '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens; 2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens'

Comment: @user2548774 then only last `2016y3m4d, SOMETHING` will be changed...do you want to change them all?

Comment: @user2548774 what do you expect output for `2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d,happens; 2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens`?

Comment: I want it to be: `2015y, balabala; <mark>2016y3m4d</mark>, SOMETHING happens; 2015y, balabala; <mark>2016y3m4d</mark>, SOMETHING happens`

Comment: I figure it out: `echo '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens; 2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens' | perl -ne 's/([^(SOMETHING)]*)\b(\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)\b([^(SOMETHING)]*?)(SOMETHING)/\1<mark>\2<mark>\3\4/g; print;'`, many thanks for your help

Comment: @user2548774 use :- `echo '2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens; 2015y, balabala; 2016y3m4d, SOMETHING happens'     | perl -ne 's/\b(\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)\b((?:(?!\b(?:\d+y\d+m\d+d|\d+y\d+m|\d+y)\b).)*?)(SOMETHING)/<mark>\1<mark>\2\3/g; print;'`..yours is wrong

Comment: @user2548774 you are using character class..it will match only single character present in `[...]`..it may work in your example but will be wrong at many palces